# Android emulator above API 28 get crash

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui

I have problem with targetFrameworkVersion

error

```
XA1006: The TargetFrameworkVersion (Android API level 31) is higher than the targetSdkVersion (28). Please increase the `android:targetSdkVersion` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` so that the API levels match.
```

when I change this target version in properties to Android Api lvl31 I cant debug project.

```
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

...and when i try to use android emulator api above lvl 28 its crash.

What to do to get API 31 working.?

Comment: Have you looked at the logs?  Have you identified the exception that causes the crash?  There is a lot of basic troubleshooting that needs to be done in order to identify the problem

Comment: There is no useful information in the logs. Just information about "deploy failed". API 28 works correctly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Things to try: * Delete bin and obj folders, try again. * Verify that you have API 31 installed (Tools / Android / Android SDK Manager / Platforms / Android 12.0 - S / Android SDK Platform 31. * Test with the OPPOSITE change: make both TargetFramework and targetSDK be 28. That should *run* on a lvl 31 device - though it won't test API 31 features - this is just a "sanity check" to make sure you can run *something* on that emulator.